# PossiblyUnusedMethod: Cannot find any calls to method in Repository

Tags: php, symfony, psalm-php

I'm working on a Symfony project and I'm starting using Psalm. Almost everything is fine, as I keep getting an error that I don't understand:

```php
ERROR: PossiblyUnusedMethod - src/Repository/PlaylistRepository.php:116:21 - Cannot find any calls to method App\Repository\PlaylistRepository::getPlaylistsFor (see https://psalm.dev/087)
    public function getPlaylistsFor( ?User $user = null ) : array
```

This function is declared as `PossiblyUnusedMethod` but I am calling it, as you can see in this code:

```php
// src/Controller/PlaylistController.php
#[ Route( '/playlists', name: 'playlists-home' ) ]
public function playlists(
    EntityManagerInterface $em,
    PlaylistRepository $playlistRepository,
) : RedirectResponse|Response
{
    $params = [
        'controller_name' => self::class,
        'playlists' => $playlistRepository->getPlaylistsForUserAuthed(),
    ];
    return $this->render( 'playlists/home.html.twig', $params );
}
```

```php
// src/Repository/PlaylistRepository.php
public function getPlaylistsForUserAuthed() : array
{
    $em = SpotifyTools::getEntityManager();
    /** @var UserRepository $userRepository */
    $userRepository = $em->getRepository( User::class );

    return $this->getPlaylistsFor( $userRepository->getUserAuthed() );
}
```

Can someone help me understand this please?

## Solution

As this function is only used in the repo, the error is cleared by changing the visibility of the method from `public` to `private/protected`.

Comment: I'm not as familiar with psalm as perhaps I should be but just for kicks try changing the visibility of getPlaylistsFor from public to private.  Psalm might be complaining about how nothing outside of the repository is calling the method.

Comment: Do you have it in a public repo somewhere? It would be interesting to look into this (potential) bug

Comment: Thanks, but @Cerad found the problem, by changing the visibility from public to private, the error disappeared. Thanks to both of you!

Answer (score 1):

Wrong positives can happen with **psalm** and it may be difficult or impossible to fix sometimes.

You can suppress psalm error using [@psalm-api](https://psalm.dev/docs/annotating_code/supported_annotations/#api-psalm-api):

```
@api, @psalm-api
```

> Used to tell Psalm that a class or method is used, even if no references to it can be found. Unused issues will be suppressed.
> For example, in frameworks, controllers are often invoked "magically" without any explicit references to them in your code. You should mark these classes with @psalm-api.

So you can use it above your method:

```
/**
* @psalm-api
*/
public function getPlaylistsFor( ?User $user = null ) : array
```